# Find the highest value and return adjacent cell until value changes in another cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am an excel novice, so I hope I am explaining my problem well enough:

[exceltable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zbrs1.png)

Field A is the District the candidate is running in, Field B is the candidate name, Field C is the percent of the vote the candidate received, and I need Field D to calculate the District winner's name.

I am trying to calculate the name of the District winner into Field D until the District changes. I know there is probably a much better way to do what I am trying to do, but here is the formula I have pieced together so far: =IF(A2="",A1,A2 (INDEX(B2:B3,0,MATCH(MAX(C2:C3),C2:C3,0))))

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this in cell `E2`:

```
=LET(rng, A2:C19, dists, INDEX(rng,,1), names, INDEX(rng,,2), 
  pcts, INDEX(rng,,3),
  distsUx, UNIQUE(dists),
  result, MAP(distsUx, LAMBDA(dist,
    TEXTJOIN(",",,FILTER(names, (dists=dist) 
    * (pcts = MAX(FILTER(pcts, dists=dist)))))
  )),
  HSTACK(distsUx, result)
)
```

Here is the output:
[image: sample excel file]

**Note**: In case there is more than one name within the same district with the same max `pct`, it returns the names delimited by comma.

Answer (score 2):

You may try-

```
=CHOOSE({1,2},UNIQUE(A2:A19),BYROW(UNIQUE(A2:A19),LAMBDA(x,INDEX(SORT(FILTER(B2:C19,A2:A19=x),2,-1),1,1))))
```

With header-

```
=LET(a,UNIQUE(A2:A19),b,BYROW(a,LAMBDA(x,INDEX(SORT(FILTER(B2:C19,A2:A19=x),2,-1),1,1))),VSTACK({"Dist","Candidate"},HSTACK(a,b)))
```

[image]